# AnimatedContainers with Row child not animating

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I would like to use multiple animated containers, one for padding and another for height, but when I use a row, it stops animating. In my simplified code sample, you can see that the "Card View With Row..." card is not animating where the "Card View No Row..." is animating.

I imagine that it has something to do with the change in width and the row. Is there something I need to wrap my row in to make it compatible with the animated containers?

My desired outcome, I want

- The padding around the column to animate
- The height of the cards' headers to animate
- The content to stay the same

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  bool cardView = true;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: AnimatedCardList(
          isCardView: cardView,
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              cardView = !cardView;
            });
          },
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
          child: Icon(
            cardView ? Icons.check_rounded : Icons.edit,
            size: 40,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AnimatedCardList extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool isCardView;
  const AnimatedCardList({
    super.key,
    required this.isCardView,
  });
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedContainer(
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
      padding: isCardView ? EdgeInsets.zero : const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
          BasicCard(
            isCardView: isCardView,
            header: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: const [
                Text("Card View With Row Not Animating"),
                Text("Edit >"),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 50),
          BasicCard(
            isCardView: isCardView,
            header: const Text("Card View No Row IS Animating"),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BasicCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget header;
  const BasicCard({
    Key? key,
    required this.isCardView,
    required this.header,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final bool isCardView;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.red,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          AnimatedSize(
            duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.blue,
              constraints: !isCardView
                  ? const BoxConstraints(
                      maxHeight: double.infinity,
                    )
                  : const BoxConstraints(
                      maxHeight: 0.0,
                    ),
              child: header,
            ),
          ),
          const Text("Card Content")
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The problem:**

Rows or Columns don't work well when their "cross axis" length is changed while wrapped in an animated widget. They already animate when their children are animating.

**The solution:**

Animate each of the children by wrapping them with the animation you want.

I created a `AnimatedHeightCollapse` widget that collapses based on a parameter. This should work for Column if you swich height with width respectively in the code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  bool cardView = true;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: AnimatedCardList(
          isCardView: cardView,
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              cardView = !cardView;
            });
          },
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
          child: Icon(
            cardView ? Icons.check_rounded : Icons.edit,
            size: 40,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AnimatedCardList extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool isCardView;
  const AnimatedCardList({
    super.key,
    required this.isCardView,
  });
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedContainer(
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
      padding: isCardView ? EdgeInsets.zero : const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
          BasicCard(
            header: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                AnimatedHeightCollapse(
                  visible: isCardView,
                  child: const Text("Card View With Row IS Animating"),
                ),
                AnimatedHeightCollapse(
                  visible: isCardView,
                  child: const Text("Edit >"),
                ),
                
              ],
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 50),
          BasicCard(
            header: AnimatedHeightCollapse(
              visible: isCardView,
              child: const Text("Card View No Row IS Animating"),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BasicCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget header;
  const BasicCard({
    Key? key,
    required this.header,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.red,
      child: Column(
        children: [header, const Text("Card Content")],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AnimatedHeightCollapse extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool visible;
  final Widget child;

  const AnimatedHeightCollapse({
    super.key,
    required this.visible,
    required this.child,
  });
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedSize(
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.blue,
        constraints: !visible
            ? const BoxConstraints(
                maxHeight: double.infinity,
              )
            : const BoxConstraints(
                maxHeight: 0.0,
              ),
        child: child,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: If you are still seeing the widget after it collapses, add clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias, to the blue container.